# No data for audienceRetention metric in Youtube analytics API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

I have a similar problem with YouTube API, that have been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37171463/no-audience-retention-data-but-columnheaders-from-youtube-analytics-api), but even if I request data with start date when I uploaded the video, I receive only headers.

Can you describe me some criteria which YouTube video must have to provide data about audienceRetention metric, because if I go to [YouTube Analytics](https://www.youtube.com/analytics) , some data from this metric are there.

In docs, there's something about video length and play count, but no specific information.

Can you please explain why some videos don't have these data, yet?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your question? And what kind of data can you see in YouTube Analytics? Can you post a screenshot of this.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. No audienceRetention metrics for the videos in my channel. I think the author wants to know, if there are some restrictions on channels or missing parameters for the non working request to work.